# custom autocomplete with angular2

Tags: angular, generics, autocomplete

I am doing a generic autocomplete, the problem is that when the user types in the input, I issue the event that performs the filter but does not change the list with the values of the filtered result in the other component.

the list of filtered results shows me empty, but by code the object returns it correctly.

```
Component autocomplete.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit,ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.css'],
  host: {
        '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
    },
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  public query = '';
  public filteredList = [];
  public elementRef; 
  private _dataSource:any[];        
  constructor(myElement: ElementRef) {
      this.elementRef = myElement;
  }

  @Output() changeFilter = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input()
  dataSource:any[];

  ngOnInit() {  
    this._dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }


  filter() {    
      if (this.query !== ""){
          this.filteredList = this._dataSource.filter(function(el){
          //___________________________________ This is my emit event:
           return this.changeFilter.emit({el:el, query:this.query});           
          }.bind(this)); 
      }else{
          this.filteredList = [];
      }  
  }

  filterAll(){
     this.filteredList = this._dataSource;
  }

  select(item){
      this.query = item.nombre;
      this.filteredList = [];
  }

  handleClick(event){
    var clickedComponent = event.target;
    var inside = false;
    do 
    {
        if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) 
        {
            inside = true;
        }
      clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
    } while (clickedComponent);

    if(!inside)
    {
      this.filteredList = [];
    }
  }
}


Component autocomplete.component.html:
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="clienteAut" type="text" class="form-control bs-autocomplete" style="width:300px;" [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)="filter()" on-click="filterAll()">
      <label for="clienteAut"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="divLista" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0" style="">
      <div class="divFila" *ngFor="let item of filteredList">
        <ul >
          <li>
            <a (click)="select(item)">{{item.CodigoCliente}} - {{item.Nombre}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Component "busquedacopiadoras.component.ts":

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClienteModel } from './../../shared/models/cliente.model';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

//servicios
import { ComunService } from './../../shared/services/comun/comun.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-busquedacopiadoras',
    templateUrl: './busquedacopiadoras.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./busquedacopiadoras.component.css'],
    providers: [ComunService]

})
export class BusquedaCopiadorasComponent {          
    constructor(private _comunService: ComunService) {}          
    clientes: Array<any> //= [];
    clienteModel: ClienteModel = new ClienteModel();

    ngOnInit() {
        //getClientes is OK
       this._comunService.getClientes()
            .subscribe((clientesData) => {
                this.clientes = clientesData as ClienteModel[];
                //this.rellenarMarcas(marcasData);
            });          
    }       
    onChangeFilterClientes(cli:any){
     return (cli.el.Nombre.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(cli.query.toLowerCase()) > -1 || cli.el.CodigoCliente.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(cli.query.toLowerCase()) > -1);
   }
}

Component "busquedacopiadoras.component.html":
<div class="campo-formulario">      
<app-autocomplete *ngIf="clientes" [dataSource] ="clientes" 
(changeFilter)="onChangeFilterClientes($event)"></app-autocomplete>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one based on similar component. You can have a look here. It works as expected:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/ng-auto-complete

Git Hub:
https://github.com/atapas/ng-auto-complete